# Populating table with json data using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

So I'm trying to populate a table with data from a script. I've tried lots changing lots of parameters etc but can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.get(file + '?op=retrieve&page=1', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                $('#mainTable').append(
                    '<tr><td>' + elem.name + '</td><td>' + elem.address  '</td></tr>'
                )
            })
        })
```

I'm currently getting the error: TypeError: e is not an Object. (evaluating 't-1 in e')

Heres a example of the json data:

```
{"id":"348141","name":"Birdies","address":"Bridge Street, Tunbridge Wells, TN1 1AH"}]
```

Comment: show us the structure of the data retrieved from the .get call.

Comment: like @MisterPositive, show with us a mock of data retrieved from the .get call , other thing, you can put a break point in $.each line and see the contents in data

Comment: @MisterPositive see edit :)

Comment: Try to add the dataType json 

$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
even if by default jQuery performs an automatic guess, but just add

Comment: Brilliant, that worked @Hatim, can you explain why?

Comment: @JL9 @Hatim : Alternatively, `$.getJSON` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

From your data, I understood that you are getting an array of js objects.

If you see your js code, you are using the following snippet

$.each(data, function (i, elem) {
});

So from the above code, "i" is the index and elem is the current iterating value.

So elem.name[i] would be invalid. This is because elem itself is an object which has name property and name is just of type string. So you cannot have name[i].

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.get(file + '?op=retrieve&page=1', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                $('#mainTable').append(
                    '<tr><td>' + elem.name + '</td><td>' + elem.address  '</td></tr>'
                )
            })
        })
```

I assume that "mainTable" element looks something like this

```
<table>
<tbody id="mainTable">
</tbody>
</table>
```